Not supporting H2-6
I have created something like an html editor. In doing this, I made the decision to only support H1, for reasons of simplifying styles/style design and picking/changing, and for selectors. So this is what I did:
css:
H1.h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13pt;
    margin-top: 0.83em;
    margin-bottom: 0.83em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

H1.h3 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

H1.h4 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-top: 1.33em;
    margin-bottom: 1.33em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

H1.h5 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-top: 1.67em;
    margin-bottom: 1.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

H1.h6 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin-top: 2.33em;
    margin-bottom: 2.33em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

So I am supporting these header styles, just using classes rather than using multiple tags. This also allows for greater flexibility, like:
H1.secTitle {
  border-top: solid blue;
  border-bottom: solid blue;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  font-size:1.5em;
}

I just wrote a JavaScript function to automatically convert H2-6s to H1 on start up in case they are present in documents that have been converted to my style convention.
If you are interested in the code (there's some jQuery in it):
First, there's this snippet from init, which is called on $(document).ready:
  if (!state.ro) { // this is a custom variable, set at the top of `init`
    //search for and replace unsupported styles
    let unsupported = document.querySelector("H2, H3, H4, H5, H6");
    if (unsupported != null && replaceUnsupportedStyles && Config.convertUnsupportedStyles) {
      replaceUnsupportedHeaders("h2");
      replaceUnsupportedHeaders("h3");
      replaceUnsupportedHeaders("h4");
      replaceUnsupportedHeaders("h5");
      replaceUnsupportedHeaders("h6");
    }

And in an optional library, I have:
var replaceUnsupportedHeaders = function(tagName) {
  let tags = document.querySelectorAll(tagName);
  tags.forEach(function(oldTag) {
    let newTag = document.createElement("H1");
    newTag.setAttribute("style",oldTag.getAttribute("style"));
    newTag.className = oldTag.className;
    newTag.innerHTML = oldTag.innerHTML;
    let $nt = $(newTag);
    $nt.addClass(tagName);
    let $ot = $(oldTag);
    $ot.after(newTag);
    $ot.remove();
  });  
}

I understand this function could be more efficient and the jQuery code could be replaced. But this conversion code would only be invoked when editing and only with documents that are not fully converted. Thus this inefficiency would only be seen once, but (theoretically) read and edited many more times.
Continuing from the last paragraph, I have coded it this way primarily for clarity, maintenance, and ease of use (my editor is set up to add/remove classes to tags for styling document elements) I imagine clients potentially wanting to create their own header classes with their own styles, and to me this seemed like the best way of enabling this. The JS code is set up to try to use document.stylesheets (or to reload via ajax if access to document.stylesheets is prevented for security reasons) to generate a list of (class) styles the the client to pick from. Documents in my editor also require a Content-Security-Policy, and doing direct element style manipulation is disabled through this.
I am especially interested if you have reasons why not supporting H2-6 tags directly could get me in trouble, or if there's a possibly better way of doing this?

I don't understand the purpose of this code. What does "not supporting" mean here? It seems trivial to "support" any HTML tags in an editor. "I am especially interested if you have reasons why not supporting H2-6 tags directly could get me in trouble, or if there's a possibly better way of doing this?" -- why not just support them?

@ggorlen re:"It seems trivial to support any HTML tags" - wrong. For example, supporting Tables are not trivial - you need a way to add and remove rows & columns. Indenting/unindenting list item programmatically is tricky. For an example of easy, P(aragraph) is easy: You can create classes "quote" or "code" or "center" for setting indents/alignment/font/etc. And then you can apply these systems to any paragraph, where applicable. It is much harder if you want a center class for all headers - if you support 6 header tags, you need your style to cover all of them. Supporting just 1 is simpler.

Code review is really quite different from Stack Overflow. Please read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users and How do I ask a good question?

If we don't understand the purpose of the code we really can't review it. Someone has already voted to close this question.

@ControlAltDel Let me rephrase, sorry for the lack of clarity: can you explain at a high-level what sort of app you're making? Is it like Notion, or some rich text editor, or something with a live preview? I still don't understand why it's not just a matter of collecting whatever HTML the user types into the editor and using outputElement.innerHTML = "the user's entered HTML". Writing 6 styles for headers seems pretty darn easy, same as you did, except with h1, h2 etc rather than h1.h5 or whatever class you invented (probably needless to say, but h1.h5 is confusing).

Maybe share your complete app, which should resolve the ambiguity here.

@pacmaninbw the original intents of not supporting H2-H6 are (a) It is much easier code-wise to handle changing from an H2 to an H3 tag using CSS classes than replacing an element and moving all of its attributes and children to a new header, and (b) Mixing H2-H6 styles with styles from CSS classes creates functional overlap and confusion.

@ggorien I want styled HTML text, but I don't want users entering HTML for 3 reasons: 1. It's too complicated for a regular non-programmer user. Even for programmers having an open/close tag matching feature is almost essential 2. Allowing users to enter raw HTML is too vulnerable to XSS. 3. By only offering CSS classes, it is easier to enforce style conventions and display versatility.

I meant to add the the above "... offing CSS classes AND a limited number of tags
